# Watch request in gmail API doesn't work

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to make a watch request using python as referred to in the [google APIs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) but it does not work.

```
request = {
  'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
  'topicName': 'projects/myproject/topics/mytopic'
}
gmail.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
```

I could not find a library or a package to use `gmail.users()` function. How do I make a watch request using an access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in gmail python client(provide by google).under main function

```
request = {
        'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
        'topicName': 'projects/myprojects/topics/getTopic'
    }
    print(service.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const { google } = require('googleapis') 
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1' })
```

gmail is just an object from the client library. In the above is the node js library. Look in the python client library for answers.

This is what I do not like about a lot of the google docs on their api, they assume you know what is loaded or have seen an example in some obscure place.