# Set up watch() with Gmail API, Trigger animation in TouchDesigner

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api

please pardon my lack of understanding with Python, Gmail API, etc.

I'm trying to set up basic functionality to trigger an animation in TouchDesigner, based off whenever a Gmail account receives a new email.

How and where would I make the following code request?

=========================

```
request = {    
  'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
  'topicName': 'projects/myproject/topics/mytopic'    
}

gmail.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
```

========================

I've made a separate python file, and it keeps telling me that "name 'labelIDs' is not defined". Am I not importing the correct libraries? Or should there be more defining at the top of the file? I ca't find any examples/tutorials that explain how to best call the watch() function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Based on the [`watch()` documentation of Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch), the [`labelIds[]`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch#labelIds) means that "List of label_ids to restrict notifications about. By default, if unspecified, all changes are pushed out. If specified, then dictates which labels are required for a push notification to be generated". For more information, check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057253/watch-requset-in-gmail-api-doesnt-work).